# Getting Deployment error settings/LeadConvert.settings is not a valid metadata object

Tags: deployment

I am deploying through bamboo plan our changes in to next sandbox but getting below error:

> settings/LeadConvert.settings is not a valid metadata object. Check
>   the name and casing of the file.

Comment: I am also getting error: objects/Event.object -- Error: SaveEdit is not a standard action and cannot be overridden.

Comment: We're in the middle of a release window, are your sandbox & production orgs on the same release?

Comment: is it related with Spring 17 release ? as my org is upgraded to Spring 17.

Comment: @DavinCasey  I think you are correct because my sandbox and production are in different release format.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, this is likely due to the current release window.

From the [Spring '17 release notes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring17_release_notes.pdf):

> Let Marketing and Sales Ops Users View Converted Leads Assign the new "View and Edit Converted Leads" permission to let marketing and
>   sales operations users view converted leads. Users can also edit
>   converted leads. This change applies to Lightning Experience,
>   Salesforce Classic, and all versions of the Salesforce1 mobile app.
>   Previously, users with both the "Set Audit Fields upon Record
>   Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" permission were
>   able to view and update converted leads. Those permissions no longer
>   grants access to converted leads. To let marketing and sales
>   operations users access converted leads, assign them the "View and
>   Edit Converted Leads" permission instead. In Lightning Experience and
>   Salesforce Classic, users with the permission can see converted leads
>   in list views, related lists, and search. In Salesforce1, those users
>   can only see converted leads in the Recent Leads list. You can’t
>   unconvert leads

Until the release window is over, I suggested removing this file from your Bamboo build plans.